# Cannot [System.Type]::GetType of type from assembly System.Configuration

Tags: powershell, reflection

I'm trying to register soap extension programatically in powershell, like it is described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/88f8dbbb-3aa9-418b-bbc0-156e023abb9d/programmatically-registering-a-soap-extension), but I have problem with this one particular method:
`[System.Type]::GetType("System.Configuration.ConfigurationElementCollection, System.Configuration", $true)`

`Exception calling "GetType" with "2" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."`

This is output from Fusion Log Viewer when running this line directly in powershell.exe:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (9/20/2013 @ 10:42:57 AM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
Running under executable  C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = xxx
LOG: DisplayName = System.Configuration
 (Partial)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/WINDOWS/system32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.
ERR: Unrecoverable error occurred during pre-download check (hr = 0x80070002).
```

This is output from Fusion Log Viewer when running this PowerGUI Script Editor:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (9/20/2013 @ 10:43:38 AM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerGUI\ScriptEditor.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = xxx
LOG: DisplayName = System.Configuration
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: System.Configuration | Domain ID: 1
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/PowerGUI/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = ScriptEditor.exe
Calling assembly : System.Management.Automation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerGUI\ScriptEditor.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/PowerGUI/System.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/PowerGUI/System.Configuration/System.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/PowerGUI/System.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/PowerGUI/System.Configuration/System.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.

*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (9/20/2013 @ 10:43:38 AM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerGUI\ScriptEditor.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = xxx
LOG: DisplayName = System.Configuration
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: System.Configuration | Domain ID: 1
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/PowerGUI/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = ScriptEditor.exe
Calling assembly : System.Management.Automation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerGUI\ScriptEditor.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/PowerGUI/System.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/PowerGUI/System.Configuration/System.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/PowerGUI/System.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/PowerGUI/System.Configuration/System.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Of course assembly is present in GAC:

```
The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:
  System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL
  System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL
```

The same problem occurs if I use assembly full name in powershell line above.

Comment: Where did you see that System.GetType takes two arguments? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx  What is the meaning of $true in your call?

Comment: @DavidBrabant: see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5cf8k43.aspx), _true to throw an exception if the type cannot be found_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the assembly-qualified type name, unless the type is in the current assembly or mscorlib.dll. This should work:

```
[System.Type]::GetType("System.Configuration.ConfigurationElementCollection, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", $true)
```

Comment: Yes, It is working now, but if I choose version 4.0.0.0 it throws again _The system cannot find the file specified_. Do you have an idea why is this happening?

Comment: @Megan powershell v2.0 runs on the 2.0 clr. It cannot load the 4.0 version because it uses a different runtime. It can't even find the assembly because there are separate GACs for those two versions.